# Erro ao utilizar @extends('layouts.app') e Route::resource - Laravel 5.7 e eloquent PHP

Tags: route

Boa tarde pessoal sou novo na linguagem e estou meio perdido,estou com o seguinte problema, criei no arquivo route/web a rota do tipo resource para minha controller chamando minha function Edit onde carrega minha view Editar.blade.php porem quando a tela é carregada mee @extends não é carregado. poderiam me ajudar ? segue abaixo meus códigos.

Arquivo route/web:

Route::resource('Aulas','CadastrosBasicos\AulasController');

Arquivo View Index.blade.php

Id)}}">A

Arquivo View Edit.blade.php:

@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
</div>
<div class="card-block">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-3 m-b-30">

<form action="{{route('Aulas.update', $Aula->Id)}}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
<h4 class="sub-title">Ritmo</h4>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="Ritmo" id="Ritmo" value="{{$Aula->Ritmo}}"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-3 m-b-30">
<h4 class="sub-title" >Dia da Semana</h4>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="DiaSemana" id=DiaSemana value="{{$Aula->DiaSemana}}"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-2 m-b-30">
<h4 class="sub-title">Horário</h4>
<input class="form-control"  type="time" name="Horario" id="Horario" value="{{$Aula->Horario}}"/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-3 m-b-30">
<h4 class="sub-title">Status</h4>
<div class="form-radio m-b-30">

<div class="radio radiofill radio-success radio-inline">
<label>
@if ($Aula->Status == '1')
    <input type="radio" checked="true" name="Status" id="Status" value="1">
    <i class="helper"></i>Ativar
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radiofill radio-warning radio-inline">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="Status" id="Status" value="0">
    <i class="helper"></i>Desativar
@else
    <input type="radio" name="Status" id="Status" value="1">
    <i class="helper"></i>Ativar
    </div>
    <div class="radio radiofill radio-warning radio-inline">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" checked="true" name="Status" id="Status" value="0">
    <i class="helper"></i>Desativar
@endif
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Cadastrar 
    

    
@stop